# Normalizing Unicode strings in Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I want to output some text that comes from a database in UTF-8 to a file in CP1252 (aka Latin1). To do that, I use Text::Iconv which works fine **unless** the characters in the string to convert are decomposed. Whether that is a failure of the iconv library or not is a question that I asked and for which the answer is not obvious. Since iconv works fine on composed characters, the solution is to normalize my strings first, but I can't seem to manage to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Hexdumper qw(hexdump);
use Unicode::Normalize;

my $v =  "É"; # E=U+0045 followed by combining ´=U+0301. UTF-8: 0x45CC81
print "'$v'\n";
print hexdump($v);

my $n = NFC $v;  # should be É=U+00C9. UTF-8: 0xC389
print "'$n'\n";
print hexdump($n);
```

But here is the output I get:

```
'É'
  0x0000 : 45 CC 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : E...............
'É'
  0x0000 : 45 CC 81 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : E...............
```

In other words, the NFC (convert to Normalization Form C) function didn't do anything. Did I miss anything? I use Perl 5.12.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.3.

This is only the beginning of my issues with text handling in Perl, which I would not have expected. Thanks for any help.

Edit: some context seems useful. Of course, my contrived example can be helped a lot by a `use utf8` clause. My actual problem is not with string literals of course.

First I realize from the answers that there's a lot I need to learn about Perl. Indeed I am not a Perl programmer, but an Objective-C/Cocoa programmer where these issues don't come up at all.

So I started to read out, and I find the Perl documentation quite confusing, for example when it talks about native encoding as differing from UTF-8. What it doesn't say is how to translate that for the Mac OS X platform where UTF-8 *is* the native encoding.

In any case the context is my program produces output in texte files that can have several formats (including csv and Unimarc), and several encodings (the four most frequent being UTF-8, CP1252, MARC8 and ISO-5426). User's choice.

It gets its input from some database (currently mySQL or SQL Server) where data is encoded usually in UTF-8 (but sometimes in CP1252).

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is clearly worded and has example code. Obviously the OP is struggling with Unicode - as many people do, in many languages. See [perlunitut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) and [perlunifaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html) for starters.

Comment: CP1252 is _not_ the same thing as Latin-1. Latin-1 is ISO-8859-1. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 for details of the differences.

Comment: You are right that ISO-8859-1 and CP1252 are not *exactly* the same. As to whether Latin1 designates ISO-8859-1 or CP1252, I'm not so sure. I've seen both. It's a red herring here though

Answer (score 3):

What you are missing is that `$v` is set to the 'E' character and the **utf-8 encoding** of the combining acute accent diacritic, not the combining acute diacritic itself. To remedy this, you'll want to do something like

1) `use utf8` -- causes Perl to automatically utf-8 decode your source code

2) explicitly decode `$v`

```
my $v = chr(0x45) . chr(0xCC) . chr(0x81);
use Encode;
$v = Encode::decode('utf-8', $v);    # now $v is 0x45 0x301
```

3) use `chr` to explicitly set `$v` to what you mean

```
my $v = chr(0x45) . chr(0x301);
```

I wouldn't really recommend number (2), but I include as a way to illustrate what is happening with your script when you don't `use utf8`.

Answer (score 2):

Ohoho, in my original message below I seem to have missed the essential bit about decomposed characters. Just tried the following for your funky letter `É`:

```
perl -C3 -lwe '$_ = qq(\x45\x{0301}); print'
```

Works fine for 5.10.1 on Cygwin.

---

I might be missing something ... but it appears you're taking a very low-level approach to text processing here.

First, you're saying that you obtain the data from a database, where the encoding is UTF-8. That's fine. So if the driver doesn't autodetect the encoding, consider telling it about it. You're not saying which database you're using, but you'll likely find something by grepping the [DBI manual](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) and maybe also the driver (`DBD::*`) you're using for "utf" or "encoding".

Then, given an appropriate encoding setting for the database connection, your text should arrive in Perl as, eh, text. Just text, no encoding. Like in Java, for instance. Yes, there is some internal encoding to the string, but you shouldn't bother what it is.

Then, when writing to the file, just use the following code:

```
open my $fh,  '>:encoding(CP1252)', $filename or die "open $filename: $!";
print $fh $text_from_db;
close $fh;
```

And that should be all you need to do.

Any particular reason you're using `Text::Iconv`? I think you should get by using the [`Encode` module](https://metacpan.org/module/Encode). But for the job outlined in your question you won't even need that.

You're using Perl 5.12.3, so Unicode processing should work fine for all but weird borderline cases. The issues are mostly with perls that date back to several years ago. The 5.12 and 5.10 series should be fine, I think. Don't have the details handy, but I once had to do Unicode work using an old 5.6.1, the Unicode support of which was experimental, and it was horrible.

Comment: I realize I have to learn a lot about Perl here. However, my experiments so far are not encouraging. One simple example: one of the encoding I need to output to a file is ISO 5426. However, opening my output file with file mode `">:encoding(ISO5426)"` fails with error `Cannot find encoding "ISO5426"`. I am not surprised that Perl doesn't know about that encoding. But now, what am I supposed to do to handle that encoding?

Comment: The database I am talking to is Microsoft SQL Server through the Sybase driver. I didn't find how to "tell" it about encoding.

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys - Did you try [setting the `charset` parameter as indicated in the perldoc](https://metacpan.org/module/DBD::Sybase)? What system are you using the Sybase client library on? What does it take to compile the client library if you don't have Sybase but only MSSQL? - To see supported encodings, do: `perl -MEncode -lwe "print for Encode->encodings(':all');"` I don't have ISO5426 on my Perl 5.12 on Win7 system either.

Comment: I did set `charset=utf8`: no change. I am using Mac OS X 10.7.3 (BSD Unix for all intents and purposes). I don't understand your compile question: Perl doesn't compile, and I installed the DBD::Sybase using CPAN. I don't know what it does behind the scene. There is no MSSQL DBD driver that I could find. Thanks for the one-liner to show supported encodings. Unsurprisingly, ISO-5426 is not on the list

Comment: After much reading, I found the solution in a section of the doc titled "Messing with Perl's Internals": I called `Encode::_utf8_on($v);` on all strings returned by the database. Thereafter, `NFC` does normalize et iconv does work (or my ad hoc ISO-5426 converter when that output encoding is selected).

Comment: Thanks for your answer that steered me towards the solution. Not that I like it: I find Perl in this case (and others) a convoluted mess at best.

Comment: @Jean-DenisMuys - "Compile" - I meant that the module will try to compile against the C driver for Sybase, which is what it is using under the hood. (At least similar drivers do, like for MySQL, Oracle and others.) - `_utf8_on`, "messing with Perl's internals": This is most likely not the way you want to go. Instead, you should properly decode the octets using `decode($enc, $octets)` or the convenience function `decode_utf8($octets)`. Not difficult and no messing necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tell Perl your file was UTF-8.

You didn't tell Perl how to encode your output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;                             # UTF-8 source.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # UTF-8 output. Don't forget to chcp 65001..

use Data::Dumper       qw( Dumper );
use Unicode::Normalize qw( NFC );

local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;    
local $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;
local $Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;

my $v =  "\x{0045}\x{0301}";
print "'$v'\n";
print Dumper($v), "\n";

my $n = NFC $v;
print "'$n'\n";
print Dumper($n), "\n";
```

(I had problems loading Hexdumper.)